# Quotient of an affine scheme by an étale finite group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, group-actions

Let $G$ be a finite étale group scheme over a field $k$ and $X=\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ be an affine scheme on which $G$ acts. The categorical quotient $X/G$ exists and may be described as $\mathrm{Spec}(A^H)$ where $H$ is the Hopf algebra associated to $G$ and $A^H$ is the coequalizer of the coaction of $H$ on $A$ and $a\mapsto a\otimes 1$.

Nevertheless, I feel uncomfortable with this description all the more so as $G$ is a finite étale group scheme and is well understood using the equivalence of categories between finite étale group schemes and finite $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{k}/k)$-groups.

Is there a way to use the latter equivalence in order to describe the quotient? I am especially interested in the case where $X$ is a closed subscheme of the affine space.

Comment: If you are comfortable with descent, then you can take the quotient over a finite Galois extension of $k$ over which the group splits and then show that it has descent data with respect to the field extension.

Comment: A minor TeX point:  you want $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ `\mathrm{Spec}(A)` or ${\rm Spec}(A)$ `{\rm Spec}(A)`, not $\rm{Spec}(A)$ `\rm{Spec}(A)`.  Even better is $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ `\operatorname{Spec}(A)`.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: @ulrich: I am still getting familiar with it. Could you please make a more detailed answer? This would be very helpful! :)

Comment: Let $K$ be a finite Galois extension over which the group scheme $G$ splits. Then $G_K$ acts on $A_K := A \otimes_k K$ and $Gal(K/k)$ also acts on $A_K$ via its action on $K$. What you need to show is that the action of $Gal(K/k)$ preserves $(A_K)^{G_K}$; the invariants of this action will then give  the quotient over $k$ that you want.